# Nullpointerexception in lucene custom analyser

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, lucene

Why I am getting nullpointerexception in `ts.reset()` line in InputFile class? If I use any inbuilt analyser like whitespaceanalyser, I don't get any exception. What is the problem here?

```
public class CourtesyTitleFilter extends TokenFilter
{
    TokenStream input;
    Map<String,String> courtesyTitleMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    private CharTermAttribute termAttr;
    public CourtesyTitleFilter(TokenStream input) throws IOException 
    {
        super(input);
        termAttr = input.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        courtesyTitleMap.put("Dr", "doctor");
        courtesyTitleMap.put("Mr", "mister");
        courtesyTitleMap.put("Mrs", "miss");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException 
    {
        if (!input.incrementToken())
            return false;
        String small = termAttr.toString();
        if(courtesyTitleMap.containsKey(small)) {
            termAttr.setEmpty().append(courtesyTitleMap.get(small));
            System.out.print(courtesyTitleMap.get(small));
        }
        return true;
    }
}
public class CourtesyTitleAnalyzer extends Analyzer
{
    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) 
    {
        TokenStream filter = null;
        Tokenizer whitespaceTokenizer = new WhitespaceTokenizer(reader);
        try
        {
            filter = new CourtesyTitleFilter (whitespaceTokenizer);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new TokenStreamComponents(whitespaceTokenizer,filter);
    }
}
public class InputFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException
    {
        TokenStream ts=null;
        CourtesyTitleAnalyzer cta=new CourtesyTitleAnalyzer(); 
        try 
        {
            StringReader sb=new StringReader("Hello Mr Hari. Meet Dr Kalam and Mrs xyz");
            ts = cta.tokenStream("field",sb);
            OffsetAttribute offsetAtt = ts.addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);
            CharTermAttribute termAtt = ts.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
            ts.reset();
            while (ts.incrementToken()) 
            {
                String token = termAtt.toString();
                System.out.println("[" + token + "]");
                System.out.println("Token starting offset: " + offsetAtt.startOffset());
                System.out.println(" Token ending offset: " + offsetAtt.endOffset());
                System.out.println("");
            }
            ts.end();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally 
        {
            ts.close();
            cta.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does tokenStream("field",sb); do?

Comment: It should analyse the string sb("Hello Mr hari...") and should return the tokens. It uses whitespaceAnalyser. But when i print 'ts', i dont get any tokens.

Comment: I guess that is trying to search the text "field" in the other text ""Hello Mr Hari. Meet Dr Kalam and Mrs xyz". In the other text, field doesn't exist, did you try sending another text like "xyz"?

Comment: Yeah. I checked. It wont search for 'field'.

Comment: If i try it with some other built-in analyzers like standardAnalyzer, i can get output.

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra - Definitely not what it does.  [See the docs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html#tokenStream(java.lang.String,%20java.io.Reader)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` is already defined in the `TokenFilter` abstract class.  You are hiding it by declaring it in your implementation.

So, just delete the line `TokenStream input;` in your `CourtesyTitleFilter`.